# web.ignoring() is not working when addFilterBefore(customFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class) is present

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

Using Spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE, `spring-security-oauth2-2.3.3`, `spring-security-web-5.2.1`.

I have set up successfully my oauth2 server and secured my endpoints using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurer`.

The problem I'm having is that when I use `addFilterBefore(customFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)` in my `ResourceServerConfigurer`. **Calling unsecured paths still try to authenticate instead of being ignored, the request tries to pass through my `customFilter()`.**

I did set up all my custom filters manually and not as beans so they won't be added automatically by spring to the filter chain, but I still get this behavior.
I also used `("/rest/**", "/api/**")` ant matchers so customFilter() applies only when encountering these paths, but I also still get this behavior.

On server startup I do see this, which is intended:

```
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/usecured*'], []
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/unsecured2*'], []
org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain - Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/usecured3*'], []
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(1) // order 1 so it applies before ResourceServerConfigurer paths
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ApiSecurityRestLoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    //...

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/usecured*","/unsecured2*","/usecured3*");
    }
}
```

My ResourceServerConfigurer

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class ApiSecurityResourceServerConfig implements ResourceServerConfigurer {

    //...

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/rest/**", "/api/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                //..
                .addFilterBefore(customFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class) // <-- when I remove this line, web.ignoring() works, otherwise it doesn't.
                //..
    }
}
```

Is this a bug or I'm approaching it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference

I updated my web.ignoring() code to this

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/usecured*/**","/unsecured2*/**","/usecured3*/**");
}
```

and it worked.